# assign a function to a global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:-

```
function test() {
    // code here
}
```

I want to assign the function `test()` to a global variable so that I should be able to call the function from elsewhere in the script using `window.newName()`. How can I assign this?

I tried `window.newName = test();`, but it didn't work. Please advice.

Comment: Tried `window.newName = test;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close:

```
window.newName = test;
```

If you include the braces, as you did, it will assign the result of executing the function, rather than the function itself.

Comment: then I can call the function like `window.newName()` ?

Answer (score 2):

When using `window.newName = test()` you are actually activating the function and that way, the variable will get the value returned from the function (if any) and not a reference to the function.

You should do it like this:

```
window.newName = test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the variable, just assign it:

```
window.newName = test;
```

If you don't need to call it using its original name, you can use a function expression as well:

```
window.newName = function() {
    // code here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `window.newName = test()`, it really means "call `test`, and assign its return value to `window.newName`.

What you want is `window.newName = test;`